# assign tasks workflows

Tags: workflow

Is it possible to create a workflow that would be placed on a tasks list that:

1. asks the person running the workflow
   for user names or groups (assignees)
2. copies the task multiple times for each person assigned to a new list

For example I would run a workflow called "read book A", and the it would ask me for peoples names which i could add as a group or singularly, then the workflow would copy the task multiple times (one for each individual).

I want to be able to run this workflow at random multiple times during the week for new people on the same original task, even though people from the original assignment may not have finished.

I can only use sharepoint designer and sharepoint web. Thanks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I only have access to 2007 right now so I'm not entirely certain how this ports to 2010.  You'll need a manually initiated workflow that has a multiple line of text column as an initiation parameter.  This will be used to input the desired users email addresses since there is no option to create a person/group initiation field.

Then you could write those emails into a person/group field that accepts multiple users as step 1 of the workflow.  Step 2 would run in parallel creating a task for each user in the person/group field you just populated.

Step 3 would update that person/group field to no value.  That would allow you to specifiy new users if needed later by initiating the workflow, and not create duplicate tasks.

You could have more initiation parameters set that you can use to populate task descriptions and titles and such.

Comment: thanks for your direction.

So your saying make a multiline column that can be used to add people to the task, then run a workflow to copy the task to all people in that column and then clear it?

Comment: Yes, but in order for it to work, I think you'll have to copy the delimited list into a separate people/group field so the tasks can be created properly.  Then you'll want to clear that column.